# Wait until all ajax requests are done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I need to wait until all my ajax functions are done, and then continue the exectution.

My particular case is that I need to translate some fields in a form before submitting it. I translate them with an ajax call to an external site. Depending on some values in the form i would need to do more or less translations. When all the translations are done (if any) I have to validate the form with ajax, and if its valid, then submit.

This is my aproach:
First, I have a function that sends the ajax call and do stuff with the data received:

```
function translate(...) {
    $("#ajaxCounter").val(parseInt($("#ajaxCounter").val()) + 1);
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success:function(data) {
            ...
            $("#ajacCounter").val(parseInt($("#ajaxCounter").val()) - 1);
        }
    });
```

Then, when the form is to be submitted I execute the following code:

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    translatable_fields.each(function() {
        translate(...);
    });
    while (parseInt($("#ajaxCounter").val()) > 0) { null; }
    if (!(this).hasClass('ready')) {
        $.ajax({
            //validation
            success: function(data) {
                if (data['isValid']) {
                    $("#form").addClass('ready');
                    $("#form").submit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
});
```

The problem is that the `while` loop in the submit function never ends.

If I execute the code without the `while` loop I can see the `ajaxCounter` input increasing when the translation functions start and decreasing when they end.

Comment: $("#form").submit(); what is that code should do?

Comment: Try using a recursive setTimeout instead of using a while loop. The while loop locks the thread so it's not possible to get new data from #ajaxCounter.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what that code is supposed to do

Comment: Instead of using a while loop use a setInterval and check the value every n milliseconds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve this in a much neater fashion using the `deferred` objects returned from a `$.ajax` call. First you should get the `translate()` function to return the `deferred`:

```
function translate(...){
    return $.ajax({
        // settings...
    });
});
```

Then you can put all those promises in to a single array:

```
var requests = [];
translatable_fields.each(function(){
    requests.push(translate(...));
});
```

Then you can `apply` that array to `$.when`:

```
$.when.apply($, requests).done(function(schemas) {
     console.log("All requests complete");
    // do something...
});
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using deferred objects, but you do not need to use `$.when.apply` with an array if you are only interested in the final completion.

Instead you can chain parallel promises using the pattern `promise = $.when(promise, another promise)`

Change your translate to return the Ajax promise:

```
function translate(...) {
    ...
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
```

and your promise loop simply becomes:

```
var promise; // Start with an undefined promise - which is the same as a resolved promise for $.when
translatable_fields.each(function() {
    promise = $.when(promise, translate(...));
});

// Wait for all promises to complete
promise.done(function(){
    // now do the final code after all the ajax calls complete
});
```

**Notes:**

- This does create an extra promise per call to `$.when`, but the overhead is very small and the resulting code is quite simple.

Comment: @Maurice Perry: As you like *elegant*, I would be interested in your opinion of this alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just loop like this: the callbacks would never get a chance to be called.

I would do something like this:

```
function translateAllFields(done) {
    var requestsInProgress = 0, doneCalled = false;
    translatable_fields.each(function () {
        ++requestsInProgress;
        $.ajax({
            //...
            success: function (data) {
                //...
                $("#ajacCounter").val(parseInt($("#ajaxCounter").val()) - 1);
            }
        }).always(function () {
            if (--requestsInProgress === 0) {
                done();
                doneCalled = true;
            }
        });
    });
    if (requestsInProgress === 0 && !doneCalled) {
        // in case translatable_fields was empty
        done();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    if (!(this).hasClass('ready')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        translateAllFields(function() {
            $.ajax({
                //validation
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data['isValid']) {
                        $("#form").addClass('ready');
                        $("#form").submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use callback

```
function translate(..., callback) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success:function(data) {
            ...
            callback(data);
        }
    });
};
```

And pass your after ajax code to it

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    translatable_fields.each(function() {
        translate(..., function(result){

            if (!(this).hasClass('ready')) {
                $.ajax({
                    //validation
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data['isValid']) {
                            $("#form").addClass('ready');
                            $("#form").submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It is not clear how your code differs from the original post. Please try to describe your changes.

Comment: Different with the original post is, I put callback there, instead of while loop to check ajaxCounter increment. But i just realise that it looping through translatable_fields. So after each callback, we can compare how many ajax return with translatable_fields.length instead.